# How to look if a char is equal to a new line

Tags: c++, windows, char, newline, equals

I have a string, the string contains for example "Hello\nThis is a test.\n".

I want to split the whole string on every \n in the string. I made this code already:

```
vector<string> inData = "Hello\nThis is a test.\n";

for ( int i = 0; i < (int)inData.length(); i++ )
{
    if(inData.at(i) == "\n")
    {
    }
}
```

But when I complite this, then I get an error:
(\n as a string)

```
binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

(above code)

```
'==' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'

'==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char [2]'
```

The problem is that I can't look if a char is equal to "new line". How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you meant that to be a `vector<string>`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`"\n"` is a `const char[2]`. Use `'\n'` instead.

And actually, your code won't even compile anyway.

You probably meant:

```
string inData = "Hello\nThis is a test.\n";

for ( size_t i = 0; i < inData.length(); i++ )
{
    if(inData.at(i) == '\n')
    {
    }
}
```

I removed the `vector` from your code because you apparently don't want to use that (you were trying to initialize a `vector<string>` from a `const char[]`, which will not work).

Also notice the use of `size_t` instead of the conversion of `inData.length()` to `int`.

Comment: `"\n"` is most certainly not a `char const*`; it's a `char const[2]`.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try == '\n' instead of "\n".

Answer (score 1):

your test expression is also wrong,  That should be

```
vector<string> inData (1,"Hello\nThis is a test.\n");

for ( int i = 0; i < (int)(inData[0].length()); i++ )
{
    if(inData.at(i) == '\n')
    {
    }
}
```

you should create a function which takes a string , and return vector of string containing spitted lines I think

Comment: inData[0] is not alway's save to use. In this case it is posable. inData is a vector, so why not use at?

Comment: @lauw I just gave him idea what's wrong , it's on him what he's doing or not.